# Is it necessary to start a new game after installing DLC?

Tags: hearts-of-iron-3

After installing the *Their Finest Hour* and *For The Motherland* DLC packs, will I get the benefit of these DLCs in my existing saved game, or will I have to start a new game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The game only needs to be restarted to take effect.
Once you have restarted the game, load your save and everything in your save should be updated with the DLC content

Comment: Confirmed this is indeed what happens :)